# Why does this return statement cause an error but the return expression doesn't in Rust?

Tags: rust, return, lazy-static

I'm confused why this code works below:

```
lazy_static! {
        static ref TSS: TaskStateSegment = {
            let mut tss = TaskStateSegment::new();
            tss.interrupt_stack_table[DOUBLE_FAULT_IST_INDEX as usize] = {
                const STACK_SIZE: usize = 4096 * 5;
                static mut STACK: [u8; STACK_SIZE] = [0; STACK_SIZE];
    
                
                let stack_start = VirtAddr::from_ptr(unsafe {&STACK});
                let stack_end = stack_start + STACK_SIZE;
                
                
                stack_end        
            };
            tss
        };
    }
```

While on the contrary, this code doesn't:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref TSS: TaskStateSegment = {
        let mut tss = TaskStateSegment::new();
        tss.interrupt_stack_table[DOUBLE_FAULT_IST_INDEX as usize] = {
            const STACK_SIZE: usize = 4096 * 5;
            static mut STACK: [u8; STACK_SIZE] = [0; STACK_SIZE];

            
            let stack_start = VirtAddr::from_ptr(unsafe {&STACK});
            let stack_end = stack_start + STACK_SIZE;
            
            return stack_end
                    
        };
        tss
    };
}
```

It's that specific return that causes an error for Rust analyzer and it confuses me. I typically use lots of explicit returns because when I code I prefer to be explicit rather than implicit but something about this error confused me because I don't understand why one would cause an error and the other wouldn't?

Comment: @cdhowie right, I didn't notice thats not a function.

Comment: It works in the Blog I'm following for making a Rust OS, but I haven't run the code I was writing it and trying to satisfy Rust analyzer.

However one returns an error seemingly and the other doesn't. The tutorial also doesn't use a return statement.

But if I am doing it wrong could you tell me what you would do differently or how you would correct it?

The blog in question: https://os.phil-opp.com/double-fault-exceptions/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` is for returning early from a function or closure.  The `{}` block is not a function, so replacing the block's final expression with a `return` statement does not create semantically equivalent code.

> I typically use lots of explicit returns because when I code I prefer to be explicit rather than implicit

Your code will be rejected by most Rust linters, then.  They will flag `return` as the last statement of a function as redundant.  `return` is for *early* returns.

Comment: Thank you, I just like the explicitly saying return but if that is bad practice I'll stop.

So I should only use return for breaking out of an if-else statement and returning and stuff.

Comment: @Thetruekingofwaffles Right. You commonly see it in `match` blocks when handling a failure scenario, to return `Err(...)` early out of a function.

Comment: I think i'll still use it sometimes but i'll get more comfortable not and stuff thank you though sir.